# Deploy Angular 4 application on Amazon Web Services

Tags: angular, amazon-ec2

Can anyone guide me on deploying an Angular 4 application
on Amazon Web Services or Godaddy Hosting?

Any help would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: If you would be interested in AWS Lambda. You can check out boilerplate created by me: https://www.angular-universal-serverless.maciejtreder.com https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-serverless

Answer (score 0):

S3 static website hosting could be one option.